# WSAEWOULDBLOCK 10035

Tags: sockets, winapi, lua, luajit

I'm trying to make client-server connection, I don't know much about sockets etc. so I used github example for luajitsocket and im getting error "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately."

So I dont even know how can I fix that, that's why Im asking here

My code:

```
local port = 8080
local address = socket.find_first_address("*", port)

do -- server
    local server = assert(socket.create("inet", "dgram", "udp"))
    assert(server:set_blocking(false))
    assert(server:bind(address))
    print("hosting at ", address:get_ip(), address:get_port())

    function update_server()
        local data, addr = server:receive_from()

        if data then
            print(data)
            assert(server:send_to(addr, "hello from server " .. os.clock()))
        elseif addr ~= "timeout" then
            error(addr)-- here
        end
    end
end

do -- client
    local client = assert(socket.create("inet", "dgram", "udp"))
    assert(client:set_blocking(false))
    local next_send = 0

    function update_client()
        if next_send < os.clock() then
            assert(client:send_to(address, "hello from client " .. os.clock()))
            next_send = os.clock() + math.random() + 0.5
        end

        local data, addr = client:receive_from(address)

        if data then
            print(data, addr:get_ip(), addr:get_port())
        elseif addr ~= "timeout" then
            error(addr)
        end
    end
end

while true do
    update_server()
    update_client()
end
```

taken from: https://github.com/CapsAdmin/luajitsocket/blob/master/examples/udp_client_server.lua

I was looking about this error on google but can't find any working solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The client code doesn't make sense. It is written to handle receive timeouts, but you can't get a read timeout in non-blocking mode. Are you sure you've copied it correctly? You should remove the line `assert(server:set_blocking(false))` and instead set whatever receive timeout you want, or none if none.

Comment: You can refer to official sample for connecting server and client using Winsock: [Complete Winsock Client Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code), [Running the Winsock Client and Server Code Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/finished-server-and-client-code).

Answer (score 1):

After `set_blocking(false)` that return code should not be considered abnormal.

You're probably getting it from `receive_from()`, which you should not be calling constantly, you should do it when `select()` or `poll()` tells you the socket has data waiting.